# How do I entertain the user while a page is taking a long time to load?

Tags: javascript, user-interface

In reference to this question:

[Chrome doesn't seem to fire javascript xmlhttprequests after a form submit, but FF and IE do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057662/chrome-doesnt-seem-to-fire-javascript-xmlhttprequests-after-a-form-submit-but)

I need a way to update the page after I hit submit waiting for the server to respond (the response can take 10s of minutes) with information from the server (as in percent complete)

In IE and Firefox I can make xhr requests while waiting for the page to load. In Chrome this doesn't work, chrome won't fire the xhr request. I never get the hit on the webserver.

How does everybody else do this?

Comment: A small game, such as tic-tac-toe or checkers.

Comment: You can use the functions you use to entertain the user in the other browsers, and after X seconds if you detect that your function "statstatechange" was not called, give feedback to the user, like "please wait, this can take several minutes" or other kind of feedback you use to the entertainment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever make your user sit around for 10s of minutes for a single page submission. They'll hate you, your server will hate you, and all kinds of problems can ensue. Instead:

1. Submit the request, and place it in a queue.
2. Return a response to the user indicating that the request is queued.
3. Update the user as the queue is processed. Either in real-time using a comet solution, or just poll it every 2-3 minutes if it's not time-sensitive.

Comment: Erm. And exactly how is this different from what I'm doing now? The user clicks the button, javascript updates a portion of the screen saying "processing report." then makes an xhr request every 15 seconds to update that part of the page with the current percentage complete processing of the report. Then when it is complete the server returns the page with the report and the new report page is displayed. It's been working for years. I only recently noticed the xhr calls don't work on chrome.

Comment: The comet wikipedia page mentioned using an iframe. Now that's a helpful suggestion. I'm going to try that.

Comment: Very different - you've got 2 requests processing :). Offload it to a queue. What happens if the request is aborted mid-process, the user leaves the page, etc?

Comment: Then the user doesn't get their report.

Comment: So I tried the iframe thing and it worked. If you set up xhr requests in an iframe fired by setinterval, they will continue to fire even after a form on the main page has been submitted. So I can use that as a workaround. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I received extraordinary feedback on a very simple queueing system I developed for users while they waited for their long running processes to finish.

Time passes more quickly when you have something interesting to read, so I pulled in rss feeds (in an ajaxy fashion) from different news sites while the web app polled the queue for process-completion in the background.  When the polling indicated complete, I simply popped a js confirm box asking the user if they wanted to keep the news window open or return to their regular workflow.

Complaints about processing times have all but disappeared since rolling out this solution.  I'm not saying it's perfect for every situation, but it certainly worked for me.